# jquery link problems

Tags: jquery

```
$(".questionsList").toggle(function() {       
                    $('#slider').animate({ left: '375' }, 500);
                }, function() {
                    $('#slider').animate({ left: '0'}, 500);
                });

                $(".questionsList h1 a").click(function() {
                       ?????
});
```

I have a div `.questionsList`, that when clicked, causes another section called `#slider` to slide out (hence the name).  Inside `.questionsList` is a link, that when clicked, I do NOT want to cause the div to slide out but instead I want to follow the link's href.

If I replace the ???? part in the code with return false; neither the jquery or the link's href fires when the link is clicked.  Thus I need help!

Answer (score 1):

This will stop the event from bubbling up and calling its ancestors' events.

```
$(".questionsList h1 a").click(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Boom baby boom thanks a ton.  I'll choose you for correct answer in 11 minutes lol...